# Memory usage by react native app increases continuously in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode7, react-native

I created a React Native project as directed in the 'Getting started' official guide. When I built the project, I got this error.

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

I got the solution here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3946
So I got the project to build by deleting the last item from the 'Build Phases' tab.

After running the app in simulator I noticed the memory usage. It started increasing gradually. I kept the app running for 15 minutes, the memory usage reached 800 MB and it was still increasing.

I also tried creating a new project but the same thing happened.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or is it a problem with react native itself.

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 and react native 0.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a memory leak when running in development mode in React Native 0.15 and 0.16 for iOS. Run in a Release scheme or update to the 0.17 release candidate.